# Building a LINQ query based on a JSON array

Tags: json, linq

imagine the JSON array to have a list of key-value pairs.

```
 <search_parameter>: <value>
 ...
 name: "John"
 age:"20"
 dept: "Development"
 ...
```

Now, I want to dynamically query the employee list based on the key-value pairs I receive. For each time, I receive a **different number of key-value pairs**.

I may receive **name** alone sometimes and I may receive **age** as well at times. It could be just the **dept** at times.

Comment: What C# data types are involved? How are you handling the JSON in C#? What do you mean by dynamically?

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without knowing details I would say you can easily add where predicates on your linq query based on the available filters.

```
public class InputFilters 
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public string dept { get; set; }
}
```

let's say variable input has search parameters.

then linq would be

```
var result = from emp in _context.Employees
             select emp;

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.name))
    result = result.where(e => e.name == input.name);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.age))
    result = result.where(e => e.age == input.age);

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input.dept))
    result = result.where(e => e.dept == input.dept);
```